# Authenticating SVN users with Apache against Linux user accounts

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, svn, authentication

Is it possible to tie authentication for SVN under Apache against system user accounts, rather than defining the passwords with htpasswd? I'd rather use Apache than SVN + SSH authentication.

Answer (score 2):

Using [mod_auth_external](http://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-external/) and [pwauth](http://code.google.com/p/pwauth/) should work. What you're actually trying to do is authenticate against PAM.